# How to refactor from mui v4 to mui v5

Tags: material-ui

I have the following style class that I want to use media query on but I am getting the following error:

> react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Unsupported style property @media (max-width: 550px). Did you mean @media (maxWidth: 550px)?

```
iconFolder: {
    fontSize: 45,
    // IPHONE 5/SE
    ['@media (max-width: 550px)']: {
        fontSize: 30,
    },
},
```

What is the right way to implement similar query solution but in **mui v5** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
'@media (max-width: 550px)': {
  fontSize: 30,
},
```